# String to javascript date in Any+Time

Tags: javascript

I'm using a javascript lib called Any+Time: http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

I do the following:

```
  var defaultConv = new AnyTime.Converter();
  var dateTime = $("#DateTimeDemo").val();
  var date = defaultConv.parse(dateTime);
  alert(date);
```

dateTime is initalized to the string `2012-11-14 19:01: CE`
But date ends up "Invalid data"?? why? Is the parser not working or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT:
By looking at the JS library source code, I think I have to pass Initialization values when creating `new AnyTime.Converter` But I'm not 100% sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes by the looks of it you have to pass a value to AnyTime.Converter(), here is mine:

```
var defaultConv = new AnyTime.Converter(
    { format: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%i: %E",
        formatUtcOffset: "%: (%@)",
        hideInput: true,
        placement: "inline"
    }
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because dateTime has an invalid date format:

> 2012-11-14 19:01: CE

It should be

```
2012-11-14 19:01:00 CE
```

I included the seconds